# Cannot use "gst_tag_id3_genre_count()" or any other id3 related api in my program

Tags: c++, metadata, gstreamer

I am trying to build a music player using gstreamer-0.10. I have to fetch metadata including the album art. I am able to fetch all the metadata except the album art. I guess i have to use id3 related APIs for this. But id3 related APIs are giving some link error as follows:

```
 gst_tag_id3_genre_count();
```

> /home/atos/Desktop/Ready_for_integration/Source/music_app/gstreamer_class.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `gst_tag_id3_genre_count'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am using Qt for the GUI. I have included `#include <gst/gst.h>` aslo`#include <gst/tag/tag.h>` and I am able to play a song even. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to link the require libraries as the documentation says:

This library should be linked to by getting cflags and libs from gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0.pc and adding -lgsttag-1.0 to the library flags.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was unable to locate gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0.pc, but I was able to locate gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.pc(check versions of files). I am using gstreamer-0.10, is there a newer version of gstreamer available?  I don't know much about linking or adding libraries using Makefile. Where and how should I do this? Can you please show me an example which I can follow?

Comment: I can now use the APIs related to ID3. I had to install gstreamer-1.0 for that. Thanks for your response again.

Comment: It would have worked the same way in 0.10. But it is a good idea to work against 1.0, as 0.10 is in maintenance mode.